# lock scene builder javafx numeric axis on specific range

Tags: javafx, charts

I want to lock Y axis of any of my charts to specific range and specific step. if there any scene builder command or javafx method for that or not:

```
chart1.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        chart2.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        chart3.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        chart4.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);

         chart1.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        chart2.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        chart3.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
        chart4.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);


 <LineChart fx:id="chart1" prefHeight="287.0" prefWidth="362.0" title="Chart 1">
                <xAxis>
                  <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                </xAxis>
                <yAxis>
                  <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                </yAxis>
              </LineChart>
              <LineChart fx:id="chart2" prefHeight="287.0" prefWidth="362.0" title="Chart 2" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                 <xAxis>
                    <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                 </xAxis>
                 <yAxis>
                    <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                 </yAxis>
              </LineChart>
              <LineChart fx:id="chart3" prefHeight="287.0" prefWidth="362.0" title="Chart 3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                 <xAxis>
                    <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                 </xAxis>
                 <yAxis>
                    <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                 </yAxis>
              </LineChart>
              <LineChart fx:id="chart4" prefHeight="287.0" prefWidth="357.0" title="Chart 4" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                 <xAxis>
                    <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
                 </xAxis>
                 <yAxis>
                    <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
                 </yAxis>
              </LineChart>
```

this is how i implemented my charts in scene builder and javafx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the range of the axis, use

```
((NumberAxis)axis).setLowerBound(double value);
```

To set the step (tick length), use

```
((NumberAxis)axis).setTickLength(double value);
```

Comment: this method does not exist . i implemented it this way
: chart1.getYAxis().set...
it is not working

Comment: Cast the axis to a NumberAxis. Edited above.